# Could not convert string to float: 'Mazda RX4' using SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I was trying to load mtcars.csv file into a dataframe and trying to replace the missing data with variable name. In my data set, i have missing value at `df[2,4]`, 3rd row and 5th column (Column name `hp`).

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6B1P.png)

I am using the following code for mean imputation:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=n.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer=imputer.fit(df)
df=imputer.transform(df)
```

But getting value error as below:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM3U4.png)

Can anyone please help me to get a solution for replacing the missing value in my data set with mean.

Comment: Please do not post your dataset/code/stacktrace as images. It's difficult to reproduce, or search for. Please edit your qestion

Comment: Completely agree with 404pio. Moreover, you reach this error because you are using categorical data (column: model) in string format. You encode it into numerical feature.  Consider even dropping it since every sample has a different "model".

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).